# Trouble aligning table cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, booktabs

I need to wrap the text in two table cells. However, when the text has been wrapped correctly in cell (1,1) and (1,3), the text on the first row in the table do not align.

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 10pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand*\rotbf[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][b]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\specialcellbold}[2][b]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\leftspecialcell}[2][b]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand*{\rightspecialcell}[2][t]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}r@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbr]
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule \textbf{} & \textbf{NIBE} & \textbf{Nilan}& \textbf{Enervent} &     \textbf{Viessman} \\
\midrule 
\leftspecialcell{Heat exchanger \\ \quad type} & None &     \rightspecialcell{Polystyrene\\plate exch.} & f & a \\
Heat source(s) & EA & EA & f & f \\
Heat sink(s) & Water & Water and air & f & f \\
Cooling option & No & Yes & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\\
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, this code looks awful. The `\label` will produce a wrong reference, since there is no `\caption` for the table

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence: Forgot to remove `\caption`. It should not be there, seeing that this is a MWE only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is uses a new columntype, (but can be switched to `p` - type) as well. for wrapping.

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 10pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcommand*\rotbf[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][b]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\specialcellbold}[2][b]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\leftspecialcell}[2][b]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand*{\rightspecialcell}[2][t]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}r@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}





\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbr]
\caption{Some caption}\label{tbl:intflow}
\begin{tabular}{L{3cm}*{4}{r}}
\toprule \textbf{} & \textbf{NIBE} & \textbf{Nilan}& \textbf{Enervent} &     \textbf{Viessman} \\
\midrule 
Heat exchanger type & None &  \multicolumn{1}{L{2cm}}{Polystyrene plate exch.} & f & a \\
Heat source(s) & EA & EA & f & f \\
Heat sink(s) & Water & Water and air & f & f \\
Cooling option & No & Yes & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\\
\end{table}


\begin{table}[hbr]
\label{tbl:intflowold}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule \textbf{} & \textbf{NIBE} & \textbf{Nilan}& \textbf{Enervent} &     \textbf{Viessman} \\
\midrule 
\leftspecialcell{Heat exchanger \\ \quad type} & None &     \rightspecialcell{Polystyrene\\plate exch.} & f & a \\
Heat source(s) & EA & EA & f & f \\
Heat sink(s) & Water & Water and air & f & f \\
Cooling option & No & Yes & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\\
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]